# JQuery - Problem with regex; Conversion of spaces to non-breaking space for one- or two-character orphans (Latin alphabet)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm a beginner and have no idea what to do to make it work in every case.
Thank you in advance for any help

I'm struggling with one problem regarding text breaking on the website.
I want to replace space with non-breaking space in cases where a one or two character word is surrounded by a space or a comma and a space. I would like to prevent the situation where there is a one- or two-character word at the end of a line

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("p, li, span, blockquote").each(function () {
    $(this)
      .contents()
      .filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // Select only text nodes
      })
      .each(function () {
        // Replace at least one space or tab around one- and two-character non-breaking words with a space
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(
          /(\s|\t)+(\b\w{1,2}|\b\w{1,2})+(\s|\t)+/g,
          "\u00A0$2\u00A0"
        );
      });
  });
});
```

Text example:
"ala i marek na że taborecie i na stole, i , na co jest, że co "
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEz39.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code helpful to you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("p, li, span, blockquote").each(function () {
    $(this)
      .contents()
      .filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // Select only text nodes
      })
      .each(function () {
        // Replace spaces around one- and two-character words with non-breaking spaces
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(
          /(?:\s|^)(\b\w{1,2}\b)(?:\s|$)/g,
          "\u00A0$1\u00A0"
        );
      });
  });
});
```

I have changed like this:

1. Added `(?:\s|^)` and `(?:\s|$)` to ensure that the spaces around one- and two-character words are properly matched without capturing them. This way, only the one- and two-character words will be replaced with non-breaking spaces.
2. Changed the replacement pattern to `\u00A0$1\u00A0`, where `$1` refers to the matched one- or two-character word.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The problem is the use of diacritical marks in the text and the fact that there can be two orphans next to each other. 
I'm trying to use the "\p{L}{1,2}" instead of "\w{1,2}" but so far without success.

Comment: Instead of a regex, I built a dictionary with orphans. So far it works